# Размещение. Элементы в ряд, flex-direction:row;

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Что нужно сделать:
Разместить элементы в ряд и сделать верхнюю панель,у меня не работает `flex-direction:row;` и элементы идут колонкой, а не в ряд:

```css
*{

    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
}
.container1{

    float: left;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15vh;

}
.panel1{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content: center;

}
.back{
    width: 100%;

}
.element{
    flex-direction:row;
text-align: center;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    display: flex;
    width: 80px;
    height: 48px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="panel1">
     <div class="panel1-1">
        <div class="element1 element" > Mac</div>
          <div class="element1 element">iPad</div>
          <div class="element1 element">iPhone</div>
          <div class="element1 element">Watch</div>
          <div class="element1 element">TV</div>
          <div class="element1 element">Music</div>
          <div class="element1 element">Поддержка</div>
        </div>
     </div>
  <div class="panel2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если ответ решил вашу проблему, примите его нажав на галочку под голосами за ответ, таким образом вы даете понять другим пользователям что проблема решена этим путем.

Answer (score 1):

Вы задаете

```
.panel1 { display: flex;flex-direction:row; }
```

и все работает правильно, но чтобы работало так как вы хотите то надо ставить стили **panel1-1**, потому что ваши элементы находятся именно в нем.

полный пример

```css
*{

    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
}
.container1{

    float: left;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15vh;

}
.panel1{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content: center;

}
.panel1-1 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}
.back{
    width: 100%;

}
.element{
    flex-direction:row;
text-align: center;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    display: flex;
    width: 80px;
    height: 48px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="panel1">
     <div class="panel1-1">
        <div class="element1 element" > Mac</div>
          <div class="element1 element">iPad</div>
          <div class="element1 element">iPhone</div>
          <div class="element1 element">Watch</div>
          <div class="element1 element">TV</div>
          <div class="element1 element">Music</div>
          <div class="element1 element">Поддержка</div>
        </div>
     </div>
  <div class="panel2"></div>
</div>
```